# Json schema validating length of one field based on another field

Tags: json, swagger

I have a JSON Schema with two fields. fieldA and fieldB, fieldA is an enum, fieldB is a string. I want to add some validations on the length of fieldB based on the value of fieldA.

```
properties:
  fieldA:
    enum:
      - VAL1
      - VAL2
      - VAL3
  fieldB:
     type: string
      pattern: '^[<a-z>{10}|<a-z>{5}]$'
```

I want to verify that if fieldA is equal to VAL1 then length of fieldB should be 5 else the length of fieldB should be 10. How to add such validation checks?

Comment: Why is this tagged "Swagger"? Do you need an OpenAPI (Swagger) solution or a pure JSON Schema solution?

Comment: Swagger is what i am looking for.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The answer depends on whether you use OpenAPI 2.0 (`swagger: '2.0'`) or OpenAPI 3.0 (`openapi: 3.0.0`).

#### OpenAPI 2.0

OpenAPI 2.0 does not support conditional dependencies. You can only document such dependencies verbally in the `description`.

#### OpenAPI 3.0

You can use `oneOf` to describe conditional dependencies in OpenAPI 3.0, similar to how you would do it in JSON Schema. The example below is based on the answers to [JSON schema conditional dependency on value](https://stackoverflow.com/q/47649038/113116).

Note while `oneOf` is part of the OpenAPI Specification (as in, you can write API definitions that include `oneOf`), actual tooling support for `oneOf` may vary.

```yaml
type: object
required:
  - fieldA
properties:
  fieldA:
    type: string
    enum:
      - VAL1
      - VAL2
      - VAL3
  fieldB:
    type: string
    pattern: '^[a-z]+$'
oneOf:
  # If fieldA = VAL1, then fieldB must be 5 chars long
  - properties:
      fieldA:
        enum: [VAL1]
      fieldB:
        minLength: 5
        maxLength: 5
  # Otherwise (if fieldA = VAL2 or VAL3) fieldB must be 10 chars long
  - properties:
      fieldA:
        enum: [VAL2, VAL3]
      fieldB:
        minLength: 10
        maxLength: 10
```

Comment: how to compare one field is less than other filed, like min < max

Comment: @AlokKumarSingh OpenAPI does not support this.